# Get Angular Material v2 slider's value while sliding

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material v2 `md-slider` in a component

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'ha-light',
  template: `<md-slider min="0" max="1000" step="1" 
             [(ngModel)]="myValue" (change)="onChange()"></md-slider>
             {{myValue}}`,
  styleUrls: ['./light.component.css']
})
export class LightComponent implements OnInit {
  myValue = 500;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onChange(){
    console.log(this.myValue);
  }
}
```

and `myValue` updates just fine and `onChange` method is being called but only when I stop sliding and release the mouse button.

Is there a way to have `myValue` update and also have the function called as I am sliding the slider?

I have noticed `aria-valuenow` attribute which is changing as I am sliding but I am not quite sure how to make a use of it for what I need (if it can be used at all).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**As of v15**

```html
<mat-slider>
  <input (input)="onInputChange($event)" />
</mat-slider>
```

```js
onInputChange(event: Event) {
  console.log("This is emitted as the thumb slides");
  console.log((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
}
```

**Before v15**

In your case, you would not listen to the `(change)` event but rather to the `(input)` event. Here is an example:

```html
<mat-slider (input)="onInputChange($event)"></mat-slider>
```

```js
onInputChange(event: MatSliderChange) {
  console.log("This is emitted as the thumb slides");
  console.log(event.value);
}
```

Comment: Great! Is there any time frame when Material beta.2 will be released?

Comment: This is not know yet. Sorry -Probably there will be a new release the upcoming week.

Comment: But there is always a way to use the super-latest version of Material 2. You an use the material2-builds | 

     npm install --save https://github.com/angular/material2-builds.git

Comment: Small typo up there, should be (input)= and it's 
    npm install --save https://... (https does not appear). But thanks, it's working fine.

Comment: @ DevVersion can i set max value for step? means now count on 100 but want 60. for example 9.60 after 10 not 9.61

Comment: Does MdSliderChange do the same thing? How do implement MdSliderChange?

Comment: This still works with the current version of Material (5.2.0). The `$event` object emitted belongs to the `MatSliderChange` class. You can access its value property like this: `console.log(event.value)`. You can use `(ngModelChange)` if you want to get the event on mouseup, and use `(input)` to get the stream of events emitted while dragging.

Comment: still working as of `"@angular/material": "~8.2.1",` :)

Comment: It would be nice to have a slider configuration (such as `updateOn: 'mouseUp' | 'input'`) to instruct the CVA to update either on `mouseUp` or on `input` event :) To folow SRP I would suggest a directive to do this instead.

Comment: No longer working with @angular/material 15, now returns an "Event" without value

Comment: I've updated the response, maybe it helps?

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to get mat-slider value inside of my component, and I got it by using event.value as shown below. Submitted this answer to help someone like me :) Thanks

```js
<md-slider (input)="onInputChange($event)"></md-slider>

onInputChange(event: any) {
  console.log(event.value);
}
```

Comment: This looks as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It merely confirms the validity of the answer provided by @DevVersion on Jan 28 '17 at 9:54.