# mat-slider: not updating immediately on drag

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I am using @angular/material in my Angular 5 app. The version of Angular Material I am using is 5.0.2. I am using @angular/animations 5.1.2.

I have a very simple use case of the slider, like this:

```
<mat-slider style="width:100%;"></mat-slider>
```

but for some reason, when dragging the slider handle, it does not move to its new position until the mouse is released, which is obviously not very good. I have checked the Material demo and that works as expected: the slider moves on mouse move, and doesn't just jump when the mouse is released.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening? It'll never pass AC at work!

Comment: do you have a stackblizt for your case?

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: Oh. I just looked it up. No, I don't I'm afraid. Can't publish too much of the code, doesn't belong to me.

Comment: You only need enough code to reproduce your issue. By the way have you searched on github issues of material2 for this?

Comment: Do you have 'hammerjs' imported?

Answer (score 66):

Wasn't working for me, even after installing hammerjs per [Step 2 Set Up Hammer JsSupport](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support).

> HammerJS provides gesture recognition capabilities required by some components (mat-slide-toggle, mat-slider, matToolTip).
>
> ...
>
> NPM
>
> `npm install --save hammerjs`
>
> Yarn
>
> `yarn add hammerjs`
>
> After installing, import it on your app's entry point (e.g. src/main.ts).
>
> `import 'hammerjs';`

However, I finally found [a comment](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4278#issuecomment-317832711) in the issues on github that solved it, basically:

```
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';

providers: [
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig },
]
```

in root.module.ts.

Comment: Awesome! Out of ten solutions, your solution was the one that was working! Cheers!

Comment: This did not work for me, adding `import 'hammerjs'` to `main.ts` like described at the provided link did the trick.

Comment: Worked for me after adding import 'hammerjs/hammer' in the actual component. NOT to the main.js and NOT to the polyfills.js

Comment: You are a life saver. This is the best solution. Thank you!

Comment: worked for me. Strangely while I was working with template driven I did not have to add the provider. When switching to reactForms it stoped working until adding the provider in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: This is also a fix for Angular and Electron desktop app.

Comment: HammerJS is no longer required for material version9++ https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/v9-hammerjs-migration.md.  Aparently?

Comment: In Angular 11 it says something like that `can not import as @angular/material is not an module`. Hmm? Rmove it and use only `HammerModule`?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, fixed by importing hammerjs in polyfills.ts

Install: `npm install hammerjs --save`

Import in polyfills.ts: `import 'hammerjs';`

If this doesn't work you might have something else going on. You should also make sure "BrowserAnimationsModule" is imported in your app.module.ts

Answer (score 5):

Their couple of Setups Need to be done for adding gesture control in material design

1. install hammerjs
   **`npm install hammerjs --save`**
2. install hammerjs types
   **`npm install @ types/hammerjs --save-dev`**
3. import hammerjs on main.ts

   > import 'hammerjs';
   >
   > import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
4. Override GestureConfig in AppModule.ts

> providers: [{ provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig
>   }]

Comment: A very big THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

I had related problem w/ value not updating, distinguishing `(change)` from `(input)` event was the trick.

Comment: Just to clarify: 
If you use `(input)="itChanged($event.value)"` instead of `(change)="itChanged($event.value)"` the component gets continuous updates.

Comment: As of Material v9, I believe this is the correct answer. Works for me on v12.
HammerJS is no longer required for material version9++ 
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/v9-hammerjs-migration.md

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896786/get-angular-material-v2-sliders-value-while-sliding

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue fixed it with importing BrowserAnimationsModule before MaterialModules.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the issue opened here https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17420

Using Angular 9 and above you should import `HammerModule` along side this import

```
import {BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, HammerModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';

imports: [
...
BrowserAnimationsModule,
BrowserModule,
MatSliderModule,
HammerModule,
]

providers: [
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig },
]
```

Comment: Tried everything else and this was the only thing that worked in our Angular 9+ app. Simple, beautiful, thanks Gil!