# How to use Angular Material without HammerJS

Tags: angular, angular-material, hammer.js

What is the proper way to use Angular Material without Hammerjs?

I don't wan't HammerJS. It is creating weird behavior (switch to another tab) when I drag my mouse inside a Material Tab Group (even when inside an HTML INPUT control) and I definitely don't want such behavior. I cannot select any text displayed inside a Tab Group.

If I don't include hammerjs, Angular complains every time. I don't thing it is a good practice to leave a warning message in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Angular Material **v12**, HammerJS is not required and not even mentioned in the [Getting Started guide](https://v12.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

Answer (score 5):

The docs are pretty clear.

HammerJS is needed for some components

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

> "Some components (mat-slide-toggle, mat-slider, matTooltip) rely on HammerJS for gestures. In order to get the full feature-set of these components, HammerJS **must** be loaded into the application."

**Update** - as of Angular 9, hammerJS is optional

Comment: or put it this way. How do I disable it, in other words, make it non-functional? As far as I understand, hammerjs is translating mouse events to finger events, but it is interfering with my normal mouse events.

Comment: looks like that is open issue with hammerjs https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1048 There may be some way using a `provide` to prevent pointer events triggering but that's beyond my ability

Comment: @alex Out of curiousity does using answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49020106/4711754

Comment: I tried and am embarrassed to find out I cannot reproduce the problem. I implemented the changes, the mouse is no longer scrolling my tabs. Good. Then I remove the changes, the mouse is still not interfering with my material tabs. I don't understand why, because I definitely have experienced tabs scrolled by mouse movement recently, definitely even after upgraded to Angular 8.